# Can't get project directory path in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, path

I'm trying to get project directory path(`My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SmartPhoneCatalog\SmartPhoneCatalog`).

tried `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` and `Enviroment.CurrentDirectory` but both return `IIS Express` folder path. (`C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\`)

Any suggestions which method to use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try with `HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath`

Answer (score 6):

Try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`.

If memory serves, this will get you to `My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\SmartPhoneCatalog\SmartPhoneCatalog\bin`, so you may have to go up one directory from here.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath
```